# Writing to socket very fast causes joined buffers

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

I have this code to test out the server,

```
var client = net.connect({port: 3000}, onConnected);

client.setNoDelay(false);

function onConnected() {
    while (true) {
        client.write('hello');
    }
}
```

using the `debug` module, I see 0ms for each request which is expected considering it is on the same machine.

The server should receive `<Buffer 68 65 6c 6c 6f>` but the server actually receives:

```
<Buffer 68 65 6c 6c 6f 68 65 6c 6c 6f 68 65 6c 6c 6f 68 65 6c 6c 6f 68 65 6c 6c 6f 68 65 6c 6c 6f 68 65 6c 6c 6f 68 65 6c 6c 6f 68 65 6^Cc 6c 6f 68 65 6c 6c 6f 68 ...>
```

Odd behaviour? Actually not, if I understand this correctly, this is happening because the write isn't flushed immediately causing it to be joined before actually getting sent.

But problem is how do I get around this and actually receive the right bytes even if the writing to the socket is very fast.

An idea is to have all the written data to be prepended with the size. Then read from that size and cut the buffer from there. But question is how do I do that?

I don't think I can do that with something like this:

```
socket.on('data', function(data) {
  var len = data[0];

  // hmmmm
})
```

So,

- Is there a way to read the stream byte by byte and cut off to every length which is specified on the first byte of every packet?
- A better alternative?
- or am I missing the point?

Comment: https://www.google.co.uk/#q=tcp+message+framing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TCP sockets implement stream communication, not packets. This means you can write 3 bytes followed by 3 bytes and the receiver can get instead 5 bytes on first read followed by 1 byte on second read.

If you want to send a packet you need to encode it down the stream yourself and the standard way is to send first the packet size and then the packet itself. E.g.

```
var szbuf = Buffer(2); // max packet size is 65535
szbuf[0] = msg.size & 255;
szbuf[1] = msg.size >> 8;
write(szbuf); // Send the size
write(msg);   // Send the message
```

The reader will need first to read 2 bytes only, compute the size and then read that amount of bytes to get the message.

If you need to use message-based communication may be using an higher level library like [0MQ](http://zeromq.org/) is a better idea.

If instead you're only writing the server and the protocol doesn't contain already a message boundary (e.g. a newline for a ascii telnet-like protocol) then it's hard (impossible) to provide reliable message passing because writing and reading boundaries are not respected by TCP and delay over the internet can be arbitrary.

This means that the client has no way to know if the message is complete or not.

Comment: assuming that the client sends only 1 stream. And that single stream contains the `<size> <the rest of the data>`. But thank you for your answer. :)

Comment: The client I'm writing a server for is already built. So I can't use 0MQ as they dropped support for raw sockets. I'm only writing the server.

Answer (score 0):

`@6502` answer was great but it was not really for my use case.

> **Warning**: I'm sharing the module I wrote to help me with my question here.

So, I saw this module called [carrier](https://github.com/pgte/carrier) but it only worked for strings, or *new line* separated data. What I needed was for a Buffer, so based on the **carrier** I wrote [**StreamFrame**](https://github.com/majimboo/stream-frame).

**Boundr** is a simple implementation of taking the length of the data which is on the first 2 bytes and just cut them there, thus **boundr** for *boundaries*. I wrote a blog post about it found [here](http://blog.majidarif.com/stream-framing-with-node-js/).

Thanks to `@vaultah` comment which helped me to find [carrier](https://github.com/pgte/carrier).

Comment: Not sure I understand. Your explanation is not exactly the first example in my answer? This means of course that you need to change the client to take in account of this size+data message packing.

Comment: Oh, right, @6502. I just realised it is. Accepted it as an answer :)

Comment: Oh also, the client doesn't send the header and the body separately. It builds it into one msg then sends it. Maybe that was why I didn't accept your answer before as you suggested sending the length and body separately. @6502